# Where can I handle navigation drawer components On Item Selected logic in android version 3.5?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-jetpack

In android studio version 3.5 they have shifted to Model View View-Model (MVVM) architecture and using JETPACK library. In previous versions navigation drawer components onClick logic can be handled by overriding "onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)" this method. In android version 3.5 they are using fragments and UI. Where and how can i implement this logic or handle onClick listeners for drawer components in version 3.5 ?
Any little help will be appreciated.